# Rename tabs based on cell value on different tab

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that has 14 tabs. I want to rename 4 of the tabs. The tabs to be renamed will use cell values on a different tab that contain no illegal characters or length restrictions.

I researched but only found where the cell values are in the same spot on each workbook.

If the cell value is blank or 0, I want to hide the tab.

Worksheets to be renamed:

- Summary 1
- Summary (2)
- Summary (3)
- Summary (4)

Worksheet with cell values for renaming:

- Overall Summary

  - cell A24 for Summary 1
  - cell A25 for Summary (2)
  - cell A26 for Summary (3)
  - cell A27 for Summary (4)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sheets("Summary 1").Name = Sheets("Overall Summary").Range("A24").Value
```

Etc...

For the cells that have blanks, you'll have to be careful with hide because you might have more than one.

Example:

```
If Sheets("Overall Summary").Range("A24").Value = <> then
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

If InStr(1, ws.Name, "Hide_", vbTextCompare) Then
    i = i + 1
End If

Next ws

Sheets("OldName").Name = "Hide_" & i

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

This one will hopefully do what you're looking for.

It looks through each sheet in the `ActiveWorkbook` and if the name contains `"Summary"` it will move down into column `A` of the `"Overall Summary"` sheet and attempt to grab the new name you want to add.

If the cell it’s looking at in `"Overall Summary"` is 0 or blank, it will rename that summary sheet to `"Hide X"` but note that it could just hide the sheets for you instead :)

```
Sub RenameSummary()

    Dim objRegex
    Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    Dim offset As Long

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If InStr(LCase$(ws.name), "summary") > 0 Then

            With objRegex
                .Global = True
                .Pattern = "[^\d]+"
                offset = CLng(.Replace(ws.name, vbNullString))
            End With

            With sheets("Overall Summary").Range("A" & (23 + offset))
                If Len(.Value2) = 0 Or .Value2 = 0 Then
                    ws.name = "HIDE " & .row
                    'ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden     'can directly hide sheet
                Else
                    ws.name = .Value2
                End If
            End With

        End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
Sub Trythis()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell in Worksheets("Overall Summary").Range("A24:A27") ‘ loop through relevant range of “Overall Summary” sheet
        If Not IsEmpty(cell) And cell.Value <> 0 Then ‘ if current cell isn’t neither empty nor zero
            Select Case cell.Row ‘check for current cell value and act accordingly
                Case 24
                    Sheets("Summary 1").Name = cell.Value
                Case 25
                    Sheets("Summary (2)").Name = cell.Value
                Case 26
                    Smeets("Summary (3)").Name = cell.Value
                Case 27
                    Sheets("Summary (4)").Name = cell.Value
            End Select
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: @Hery0502, any feedback?